# Automatic borders in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, border

I have a worksheet that automatically colors a row when column A is filled with certain text.  What I want is to also have a thick black border appear above each colored cell, and not appear above any unfilled cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional formatting > New Rule >  "Format only cells that contain"

[image]